# How can i get current url fo the tab in my popup.js file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi there i am trying to get current url of the active tab in my popup.js file and below is the code i am using but somehow it's not working so can you please help me what's wrong with it. Thank you in advance.

```
function getAmazonURL()
{
    alert("ok");
    $url = "";
    chrome.windows.getAll({
    }, function(windows) {
        for (var i in windows) {
            var tabs1 = windows[i].tabs;
            for (var j in tabs1) {
                var tab = tabs1[j];
                if(tab.active)
                {
                    $url = tab.url;alert(tab.url);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    getAmazonURL();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the active tab all you have to do is use [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query). For example:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tab){
  //Be aware that `tab` is an array of Tabs 
  console.log(tab[0].url);
});
```

Comment: Hi @BeardFist thank you for your reply but when i am trying to use below code it alerts me undefined in popup.                       $url = console.log(tab[0].url); 
        alert($url);

Comment: @Keyur Naturally it alerts `undefined`. `console.log` doesn't return anything so `$url` is undefined.

Comment: @Keyur did you not try actually alerting the url? `alert(tab[0].url)`  There is no need to use a local variable to store it first... and I find it more useful to use `console.log` instead of `alert` especially in popups as it doesn't block execution.

Comment: You might get an `undefined` value as return if you do not have the `tabs` permission in your extension manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAmazonURL()
{
    $chromeurl = "";
    chrome.windows.getAll({
        "populate":true
    }, function(windows) {

        for (var i in windows) {
            var tabs = windows[i].tabs;
            for (var j in tabs) {
                var tab = tabs[j];
                if(tab.active)
                {
                    $chromeurl = tab.url;
                }
            }
        }
        alert($chromeurl);

        return $chromeurl;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    getAmazonURL();
});
```